# access controls for each layer of a service in ArcGis for Server

Tags: security, service, arcgis, arcgis-server

I created a map in ArcGis desktop and published it to ArcGis for server 10.2. A service was created in arc server. Suppose i have two client A and B. A has high privilege and must see all layers in the map but B should only see some of layers. How can i manage privilege access for these client in Arc Server? I don't want to handle it in client side, i want to some how configure  arc server so that it manages what layer in a service should be accessed by a specific client.
any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Rights are managed on a map service level only. Two options for you : 
- create a map service for each profile and grant it for the allowed users. (suitable for read-only operations) 
- or implement a server proxy that will filter the rights depending on user rights. 
(cost in time, because of dev)

Comment: thanks @frett27 . I found something called feature services. I believe in ArcGIS Server 10.1 there is feature-level [ownership-based access control](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0154000004n9000000). After a bit more research I found [this product](http://www.conterra.de/en/misc/news/detail.asp?id=446)